# Finding all paths between source and destination vertex in Graphx - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, breadth-first-search, spark-graphx

I want to get all vertices and edges between 2 given vertices(source and destination) in Graphx. So, I think about finding all paths between 2 vetices and then to remove duplicate edges.

here is the shortest path code that I'm following from this [link](https://gist.github.com/ankurdave/63acd24ef744aaac87e0):

```
/**

* Returns the shortest directed-edge path from src to dst in the graph. If no path exists, returns
* the empty list.
*/

def bfs[VD, ED](graph: Graph[VD, ED], src: VertexId, dst: VertexId): Seq   [VertexId] = {
 if (src == dst) return List(src)

 // The attribute of each vertex is (dist from src, id of vertex with dist-1)
 var g: Graph[(Int, VertexId), ED] =
   graph.mapVertices((id, _) => (if (id == src) 0 else Int.MaxValue, 0L)).cache()

 // Traverse forward from src
 var dstAttr = (Int.MaxValue, 0L)
 while (dstAttr._1 == Int.MaxValue) {
   val msgs = g.aggregateMessages[(Int, VertexId)](
     e => if (e.srcAttr._1 != Int.MaxValue && e.srcAttr._1 + 1 < e.dstAttr._1) {
      e.sendToDst((e.srcAttr._1 + 1, e.srcId))
     },
     (a, b) => if (a._1 < b._1) a else b).cache()

   if (msgs.count == 0) return List.empty

   g = g.ops.joinVertices(msgs) {
    (id, oldAttr, newAttr) =>
     if (newAttr._1 < oldAttr._1) newAttr else oldAttr
   }.cache()

   dstAttr = g.vertices.filter(_._1 == dst).first()._2
 }

 // Traverse backward from dst and collect the path
 var path: List[VertexId] = dstAttr._2 :: dst :: Nil
 while (path.head != src) {
   path = g.vertices.filter(_._1 == path.head).first()._2._2 :: path
 }
 path
}
```

I'm trying to modify it to get all paths instead of just shortest one. I am only able to get largest or shortest path. How can I get list of lists containing all paths?

Comment: If a java example might help, see (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/48718818/3992939]

Comment: thanks @c0der , I figured it out. I find shortest path and then disabled this path and then find next. Until there is no more path left.

Comment: @Nargis Can you please explain what do you refer to by "disable"? I tried following your approach by removing the path discovered from the graph but if fails since a node in the first shortest path is often a junction through which other paths go through. Is there a way to disable the path discovered other than by deleting it?