# Finding ALL shortest paths between two nodes in a graph having a multidimensional predecessor array

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search, graph-traversal

so I've been trying to look up ways to find ALL shortest paths between two specific nodes in an unweighted graph and I've written code up to the point where I have built up a "predecessor" array that keeps track of what nodes I have used to reach the given node. This array is a multidimensional array so for example, if the shortest path from A to D can be from A > B > D OR A > C > D then the predecessor array will look like this (where the first row is the index, and then rows below are a multidimensional array):

```
A    | B    | C    | D    | 
---------------------------
     | A    | A    | B    |
---------------------------
     |      |      | C    |
```

But now I am lost as to how I can find every permutation in this predecessor array to get every possible combination of shortest paths possible to then print out e.g I would like to print out:

```
All shortest paths:
A > B > D
A > C > D
```

I have heard people say you can do this by recursion? But am very lost. (Also please note that I am not too worried about time complexity). Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: See an example of [finding all possible paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48718818/3992939)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have heard people say you can do this by recursion?

I'm not sure what they have in mind when saying this, but I'm giving you a simple way to solve this, and it will solve this in good time complexity as well. Solve this situation using BFS. IMO, this is your best bet.

**Solution**:

```
Example graph:
(A,B,C,D,E)
A->B, A->C, B->D, B->E, C->E, D->E

Source: A, Destination: E
Paths: (marked with # are solution paths)
# A->B->E
# A->C->E
  A->B->D->E
```

1. Start with the source node. Keep a queue, with each element having 3 information points:

   - Node
   - Level
   - Path (till now)
2. Do a BFS on the graph. At each level, check if destination is reached. Continue this until it is done.
3. When you reach the destination on a certain level, don't stop there as we do in usual cases. You need to complete this level fully and stop when you are done with this level.
4. Print all paths for destination, this will be your answer.

**Working this on our example:**

- Each element of queue is represented as a 3 value tuple (Node, Level, Path)

Initial Queue: (A,0,null)

```
Level         Queue
 0            (A,0,null)
 1            (B,1,A)
 1            (C,1,A)
 2            (D,2,AB)
 2            (E,2,AB)      #       --> found destination, so, complete L2 fully
 2            (E,2,AC)      #
 3...stop
```

Print paths: ABE and ACE from above.

Comment: How do you go about printing all paths from the queue? How do you interpret that paths from the queue in the example given?

Comment: @FallonX `Path for current node = (Path from prev node + prev node)`, eg. you visit B from A, path = null+'A' = A. eg2. you visit E from C, path = 'A' + 'C' = AC

Comment: Yep, got it. Thanks!